# Spring boot deploy configuration file

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I have created a spring web boot executable jar and configured AWS to start it:

```
$sudo chkconfig --list fake-spi-endpoint
fake-spi-endpoint       0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

According to [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-script-customization-conf-file) I created a configuration file with the same name:

```
$ls -l
-rwx------ 1 ec2-user ec2-user 17024045 Jul 19 13:18 fake-spi-endpoint-1.0.0-boot.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user       37 Jul 19 13:40 fake-spi-endpoint.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user       32 Jul 19 13:16 fake-spi-endpoint.jar -> fake-spi-endpoint-1.0.0-boot.jar
```

The configuration overrides a log directory:

```
$cat fake-spi-endpoint.conf
-LOG_FOLDER=/home/ec2-user/service/logs
```

But when I start this service it seems to *execute* the configuration file content:

```
$service fake-spi-endpoint start
/home/ec2-user/service/fake-spi-endpoint.conf: line 1: -LOG_FOLDER=/home/ec2-user/service/logs: No such file or directory
Started [1995]
```

Where is the issue?

Comment: "I have [..] configured AWS to start it" - so, how did you do this?

Comment: All commands are in the question.

Comment: I don't see a mention how have you configured fake-spi-endpoint service.

Comment: ah, I think that is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems you are confusing [spring boot configuration file](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-script-customization-conf-file) with [upstart service configuration file](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/the-upstart-event-system-what-it-is-and-how-to-use-it).

You should have fake-spi-endpoint.conf, the spring boot configuration file, in the same place your .jar is, for example `/home/ec2-user/app/fake-spi-endpoint`.

**In addition** you should have a service configuration file that tells how to launch your app in, apparently, `/home/ec2-user/service/fake-spi-endpoint.conf`. That file should contain something like

```
exec java -jar /home/ec2-user/app/fake-spi-endpoint/fake-spi-endpoint.jar
```

Which tells upstart how to start your application. You're mixing the two which is why upstart tries to execute your spring boot config file.

You can read more details on using upstart (and other service managers) to launch spring boot applications here:

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-app-as-a-service

Comment: Spring boot page says: "For example, a jar named /var/myapp/myapp.jar uses the configuration file named /var/myapp/myapp.conf, as shown in the following example. JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1024M LOG_FOLDER=/custom/log/folder". And I did exactly that. Is it wrong?

Comment: @LeosLiterak as I explained in the answer, it is not wrong for spring boot configuration, but you need a separate configuration file for upstart. it is wrong to use spring configuration file as upstart configuration file, they are two different things.

Comment: I am sorry but I still did not get it. Even upstart manual says that conf shall go to /etc/init, not side by side of the binary.

Comment: @LeosLiterak yes, that is what I am saying as well - upstart configuration shouldn't go side by side the binary, spring boot configuration should

Comment: you should have two folders, one with your jar & spring boot config file, and another with upstart config file. normally upstart config file goes into `/etc/init`, but based on your description, in aws it is reading it from `/home/ec2-user/service/`. But your app shouldn't be in the same directory, which is why I was suggesting `/home/ec2-user/app/fake-spi-endpoint/` for your app.